# will chaging the datacontext of a user control cause the property changed events to fire?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control on which I am planning to switch out the datacontext on certain events. The control has several text boxes and a list view, etc.. etc... The question is will simply saying view.DataContext = new viewModel(); be enough? or will have have to tell all of the property changed events to fire?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that it will fire the changed events when you change the DataContext. But why not try it?

Comment: Ha! I knew someone would say that - I am working on trying it as we speak but I was hoping to know before before I did a whole bunch of refactoring. And really - beside the fact it may work the other reason for asking is someone may say something like "Yes, that will work but it's a bad idea cause X" or whatever...

Comment: That's fine, it's just that often it's quicker to test some of the questions than wait for for answer :) What do you need to refactor? You can just create a temporary viewModel, test it, then delete the viewModel.  Or create a new project with two viewModels and switch between them. As for whether or not it's a bad idea, you should add that to the original question in case someone doesn't read the comment.

Comment: Right I am not giving you a hard time and yes my thought process was create a test project vs. refactor the current project I am working on and see if it works - I probably should have created a test project it would have been faster.

Comment: I'd answer your question if I knew for sure and I'm sure someone else will. I'm not trying to be authoritative or anything, it's just advice. Unfortunately, the web has a way of distorting the tone of the message :)

Comment: The simple answer is yes, see my experience in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389040/problem-with-selecteditem-of-wpf-editable-combobox-with-datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WPF will automatically update the UI bindings if the DataContext behind the UI controls changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  However - you need to consider the scope of the data context change for performance reasons.  If your context change affects the entire form - it could slow down the application.  Use the profiling tools for WPF to see the affects of this.